# removing texture

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am having some problem with removing my spritesheets after my scene exit..

I basically follow Ray's instructions by removing unused textures in init

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
```

and in dealloc I have

```
CCTexture2D * texture = spriteNode.textureAtlas.texture;
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromTexture:texture];
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:texture];
```

[Reference](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8&p=4378#p2287)

This works fine if the transition to scene is not the current scene.
But when I tried to "restart" the current scene it crashes.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:2.0 scene:[currentScene scene] withColor:ccBLACK]];
```

Seems like the problem is that when replacing the current scene by the "new" current scene.. the "new" current scene init is called before the current scene is deallocated. Hence my "new" current scene spritesheet got deallocated right after it's being created.

How can I properly remove the spritesheets in this case?
Or is my approach to restart the current scene incorrect?

Update:
I was trying to add a loading scene as advised but couldn't make it work.. here's my loading scene

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
LoadingLayer * layer = [[[LoadingLayer alloc]init]autorelease];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}


-(id) init{

  if(self = [super init]){

    winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    CCLabelTTF * loadingLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Loading..." fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:30];
    }

    loadingLabel.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [loadingLayer addChild:loadingLabel];

    [self scheduleUpdate];

  }
return self;
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)dt{

 [self unscheduleUpdate];
 NSString * bgPlist = @"backgroundsIPAD.plist";;
 NSString * hudPlist = @"hudSpritesIPAD.plist"
 NSString * gameOnePlist = @"gameOneSpritesIPAD.plist";

// load background
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:bgPlist];

// load hud
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:hudPlist];

// load sprites
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:gameOnePlist];

 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:2.0 scene:[GameTwoLayer scene] withColor:ccBLACK]];
}
```

This will give me a splash of the GameTwoLayer in this case, then a black screen..
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the new scene's init runs before your current scene is deallocated. Makes sense, since you're creating a new scene object within your current scene object.

You should not remove textures etc during init for that reason. It's just not the right place to do so. The scene that has been using the resources should be responsible for removing those resources. Removing textures etc should be done in the dealloc method of the scene.

If you need to avoid the memory spike with both scenes in memory at the same time, you'll have to add an in-between "loading" scene so that the previous scene will be deallocated before the next scene starts.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I tried adding a loading scene in between but the result is weird. Basically I have my current scene calls replaceScene with the LoadingScene.. then inside LoadingScene I have it call replaceScene with my "new" current scene after some delay. But what I see is a splash of the "new" current scene and then the loading screen. Any insight?